# Trying to transition a UIImageView out of a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am trying to transition a UIImageView out of a UIScrollView, but cannot find any way of achieving my desired result.

I will try and explain... I have a UIScrollView that contains a number of UIImageViews. When I make a long press on one of these UIImageViews I would like it to flip over to another UIImageView, while moving to the centre of the screen (out of the bounds of the UIScrollView). Basically, I have a range of cards displayed at the bottom of the screen and when a user presses on one of these, I want it to flip over and reveal the back in the centre of the screen.

What I currently have is on each card a container UIView, containing front and back. This way I can flip the card while moving it to the centre of the screen (and incidentally increasing the frame size). The code I am using for this is:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:cardView
    duration:0.5
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft | UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
    animations:^
        {
        [mainView removeFromSuperview];
        [cardView addSubview:reverseView];
        [cardView.superview bringSubviewToFront:cardView];
        cardView.frame = CGRectMake(176.0, 70.0, 128.0, 180.0);
        }
    completion:NULL];
```

This works wonderfully while there is no UIScrollView but as soon as I introduce the UIScrollView, it all breaks down because I need clipsToBounds to be YES, so I cannot display this at the centre of the screen.

So I have now tried moving the container view out of the scrollView and then proceeding as before:

```
UIView *gameView = cardView.superview.superview;
[cardView removeFromSuperview];
[gameView addSubview:cardView];
cardView.frame = [self getOriginalFrameForCard:card];
```

Here is where my real problem starts: if I just run this code and then don't apply the centring transition, it works fine: the UIImageView doesn't move on the screen, but it is no longer within the UIScrollView. If however, I DO run the transition from above after this, the initial side of the card just vanishes before the back of the card flips in from nothing.

On some further testing, I can do the reverse of this operation fine by putting the code to return the card into the UIScrollView in the completion block of the animation. It seems that the code to render the front of the card into the main window isn't firing before the transition is carried out.

Sorry for the essay, just trying to explain the situation as fully as I can

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the desired effect by wrapping the transition code within an NSTimer on a delay of 0.0 like so:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(animateToMiddle) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

This feels slightly dirty, if anyone can give me a better solution, I will happily accept. Also, if I am completely misusing the transition system, please let me know. I have not been using Objective-C for particularly long and there are many things that I don't properly understand.